# How to send a discord promt using python script to a discord server(channel) with a bot midjourney?

Tags: python, discord, api-key

I want to generate images using external commands and i wrote :

```
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/numberss/messages"
    auth = {
        'authorization': 'checked from ctrl+shift+i'
    }
    msg = {
        'content':'/imagine dog with sun'
    }
    requests.post(url, headers=auth, data=msg)
```

discord displays '/imagine dog with sun' but as plain text not promt

i need to get url adrres of generated image as a feedback to my python script

Comment: There is no support for sending slash commands in the discord API, unfortunately. Thus, it isn't possible to interact with midjourney using a python script using said API.

Comment: Is there any other way?

Comment: Unfortunately, not without going against discord's extensive TOS for Client Automation etc. Sorry! Have you tried looking into midjourney's own API?